# How do I check whether my app is allowed to post notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

Users can turn off notifications for individual apps in Android settings. Is there a method like `isNotificationsAllowed()` that allows me to check whether my app is allowed to post notifications? Also, how do I open the Android settings screen to guide my users to turn on notifications?

Comment: This could help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145343/checking-android-system-security-notification-access-setting-programmatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 4.1: How to check notifications are disabled for the application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application)

Comment: You can checkout my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57769424/4655711
The same solution applies.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**EDIT - New Answer:**

Seems like google added the proper API call:
`NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()`

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

For anyone who is looking at this question, note that NotificationListenerService is different from "Show Notification". **These two are different things**! If an app has access to `NotificationListenerService` does not mean that its notifications are shown and vice versa. In order to check if user has blocked notification from your app or not, you can use reflection:

```
public class NotificationsUtils {

private static final String CHECK_OP_NO_THROW = "checkOpNoThrow";
private static final String OP_POST_NOTIFICATION = "OP_POST_NOTIFICATION";

public static boolean isNotificationEnabled() {

    AppOpsManager mAppOps = (AppOpsManager) GlobalContext.getContext().getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);

    ApplicationInfo appInfo = GlobalContext.getContext().getApplicationInfo();

    String pkg = GlobalContext.getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName();

    int uid = appInfo.uid;

    Class appOpsClass = null; /* Context.APP_OPS_MANAGER */

    try {

        appOpsClass = Class.forName(AppOpsManager.class.getName());

        Method checkOpNoThrowMethod = appOpsClass.getMethod(CHECK_OP_NO_THROW, Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, String.class);

        Field opPostNotificationValue = appOpsClass.getDeclaredField(OP_POST_NOTIFICATION);
        int value = (int)opPostNotificationValue.get(Integer.class);

        return ((int)checkOpNoThrowMethod.invoke(mAppOps,value, uid, pkg) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38482

Comment: AppOpsManager was added in API level 19 (Android 4.4), so this can only be used for API level 19+

Comment: @nibarius Yes, you are correct. But: starting 4.4 users are allowed to kill the notification on app level. So below 4.4, it is safe to assume that notifications are enabled (unless running on a tampered ROM)

Comment: @Kasra I just tested with a Samsung Galaxy Grand which runs Android 4.2.2 and I can kill notifications on the app level there as well. This SO question also say that it can be done on the app level from 4.1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11649151/android-4-1-how-to-check-notifications-are-disabled-for-the-application

Comment: @nibarius my bad. 4.1-4.4 is where things get a bit blurry. Please see my updated answer. If you look into the source code for NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled(), you will see that it uses a different logic for each android version (it uses AppOpsManager internally as well). Anyways, this should be the most reliable way as it's made by android team.

Comment: Hi @kasra, this method is working fine less than Android 8. but this method is always returning true in latest android-8(Android - Oreo).

Answer (score 67):

```
NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()
```

seems like a way to go.

Comment: I tested this by manually changing the notifications permissions in settings and it worked fine, boolean was returned correctly in both cases.  Great one-line solution.  And just in time  .. I was searching for the solution only a few hours after this answer was posted .. so good timing :)  Thanks!

Comment: @gnB nice! glad it helped ;)

Comment: NotificationManagerCompat.From(context).AreNotificationsEnabled();

Answer (score 12):

Here is more complete answer to this question

```
fun areNotificationsEnabled(context: Context, channelId: String = "fcm_fallback_notification_channel"): Boolean {
    // check if global notification switch is ON or OFF
    if (NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled())
        // if its ON then we need to check for individual channels in OREO
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val manager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val channel = manager.getNotificationChannel(channelId)
            return channel?.importance != NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
        } else {
            // if this less then OREO it means that notifications are enabled
            true
        }
    // if this is less then OREO it means that notifications are disabled
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Is there a way an app can check if it is allowed to access notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813321/is-there-a-way-an-app-can-check-if-it-is-allowed-to-access-notifications)

And there's a bit more explaination here:

[Check for access to notifications using NotificationListenerService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097583/check-for-access-to-notifications-using-notificationlistenerservice/21392852#21392852)

Comment: This is for NotificationListenerService, which is different from SHOW NOTIFICATION!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled())
{
 //Do your Work
}
else
{
     //Ask for permission
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Main Code Below-
//NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()
       if(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).areNotificationsEnabled())
       {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Notification is on for this Application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       else
       {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Notification is off for this Application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

2023-03-18: Android 13 (SDK 33 TIRAMISU) has introduced a new runtime permission (***android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS***) for app to post notifications (which was allowed by default before Android 13).

If you app's target SDK is lower than 33 and running on Android 13 device, the first time user opens your app system will automatically request this permission then it's up to user to decide if your app is allowed to post notifications.

If your app targets to SDK 33 and running and Android 13 device, posting notification is **NOT ALLOWED** by default, until you explicitly request it and user allows it.

And note that user may allow your app to post notifications but meanwhile disable a specific notification channel, therefore it is not good enough to only test if the permission is granted, but also need to test if the notification channel is enabled.

Below is a sample helper function (in Kotlin) to check is notification allowed:

```
fun isPermissionGranted(context: Context, permission: String): Boolean =
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

fun isNotificationAllowed(context: Context, channelId: String? = null): Boolean {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        if (!isPermissionGranted(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)) return false
    }
    if (!NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).areNotificationsEnabled()) return false

    if (channelId == null) return true
    runCatching {
        val mgr = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val channel = mgr.getNotificationChannel(channelId)
        return channel.importance != NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Context.areNotificationsEnabled(): Boolean {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS,
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val manager =
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        if (!manager.areNotificationsEnabled()) {
            return false
        }
        val channels = manager.notificationChannels
        for (channel in channels) {
            if (channel.importance == NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE) {
                return false
            }
        }
        true
    } else {
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).areNotificationsEnabled()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(), "enabled_notification_listeners").contains(getActivity().getPackageName())) {
    // Notification access service already enabled
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"notification enabled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$AppNotificationSettingsActivity");
    intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
    intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: This is for NotificationListenerService, which is different from SHOW NOTIFICATION!!!