# Enable main mobile notification in android through another app?

Tags: android, notifications

If the app notification is enabled, and the main mobile notification is not enabled, we will not get the notifications, so how to enable the main mobile notification? I tried a lot, but I didn't get it, please help me to sort out this problem.

How to check whether the mobile notification is enabled or disable in android from another app? I Want to turn on mobile notification from my app.

Comment: _Hello Bhavani! Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you add some more details about what  problem you facing? with some more code so some of will able to understand and help you?_

Comment: your answer is here [allowed-to-show-notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815782/how-to-check-if-my-app-is-allowed-to-show-notification)

Comment: The requirement is set the notifications ,in that if our app notification is enabled and main notification bar is disabled for all apps,How to enable the main notification or check the notification is enable or not ?