# How to check if user has granted app the permission for POST_NOTIFICATIONS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to know in my application, that user in own phone > setting > app notification > for this application set a notification or not.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check whether my app is allowed to post notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27815782/how-do-i-check-whether-my-app-is-allowed-to-post-notifications)

Answer (score 0):

From android 13, we need to request the `android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS` permission at runtime. So we can use the following code to check and request the notification permission in the `Activity`'s `OnCreate` or `OnStart` method:

```
const int requestNotification = 0;
string[] notiPermission =
  {
      Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications
  };

if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 33) return;
if (this.CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications) != Permission.Granted)
   {
      this.RequestPermissions(notiPermission, requestNotification);
   }
```

Note:

1.For more information, please check document: [Notification runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission), [Request runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#:%7E:text=To%20check%20whether%20the%20user%20already%20granted%20your,depending%20on%20whether%20your%20app%20has%20the%20permission.) and [Permissions In Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows).

2.And there is an official sample here, you can check it here: [Runtime Permission Sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/android-m/RuntimePermissions).

3.The `Manifest.Permission.PostNotifications` can only be used in the .net7.0 and higher.